# Why do we define INT_MIN as -INT_MAX - 1?

Tags: c, types, integer, signed

AFAIK this is a standard "idiom"

```
#  define INT_MIN   (-INT_MAX - 1)  
#  define INT_MAX   2147483647
```

Question: Why is the definition of INT_MIN not as -2147483648?

Comment: if you define both of them separately, when you want to do a modification, you have to remind yourself to change both. if one of them relies on the other one, then you can just change one and the change will apply to both.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr:I read that there is a reason but there was no explanation of that reason (was related to compilers and not code design)

Comment: unfortunately i don't have gcc with me currently. but i think you can try `int foo = -2147483648;` directly and see if compiler complains. i am curious about the result.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the fact that when I mark it as "possible duplicate" it gets stamped "duplicate" immediately. But anyway, the question has been asked many times before.

Comment: @AndreyT I concur. It was nice and all that said-power to insta-dupe was granted to those of us with enough insanity to build high-rep, but I would have preferred if they would have given an *option* to old-style nominate it as a duplicate as an alternative if we feel it is one, but would like the extra weight of our fellow members behind it. I wouldn't think it would be a hard feature to add. Maybe something to hurl around on meta.

Answer (score 17):

Because `2147483648` is a `long` value as it does not fit in an `int` (in common system with 32-bit `int` and 64-bit `long`, on system with 32-bit `long` it is of type `long long`). So `-2147483648` is of type `long`, not `int`.

Remember in C, an unsuffixed decimal integer constant is of the first type `int`, `long` or `long long` where it can be represented.

Also in C `-2147483648` is not a integer constant; `2147483648` is an integer constant. `-2147483648` is an expression formed with the unary operator `-` and the integer constant `2147483648`.

**EDIT:** if you are not convinced `-2147483648` is not of type `int` (some people in the comments still seem to doubt), you can try to print this:

```
printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof INT_MIN, sizeof -2147483648);
```

You will most likely end up with:

```
4 8
```

on common 32 and 64-bit systems.

Also to follow a comment, I'm talking about recent C Standard: use c99 or c11 dialect to test this. c89 rules for decimal integer constant are different: `-2147483648` is of type `unsigned long` in c89. Indeed in c89 (it is different in c99, see above), a unsuffixed decimal integer constant is of type `int`, `long` or `unsigned long`.

**EDIT2**: [@WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) added another example (but for C++) to show `-2147483648` is not of type `int`.

The following example, though in C++, drives home this point. It was compiled with a 32-bit architecture g++. Note the type info gathered from the passed parameter deduction:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

template<typename T>
void foo(T value)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    foo(-2147483648);
    foo(INT_MIN);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
void foo(T) [T = long long]
-2147483648
void foo(T) [T = int]
-2147483648
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. This `-2147483648` is considered a `long`?

Comment: More to the point. unary minus is applied to an *expression*, the type of which has already been established by the *value*. `2147483648` as a value (before applying unary-minus) is not representable as `int` on a 32bit system.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP asked, as INT_MIN is defined using INT_MAX, OP's wondering why INT_MIN is not defined by using a constant (like INT_MAX).

Comment: @WhozCraig:What you say makes sense

Comment: @Cratylus is what ouah said, just in different words. Same premise.

Comment: my opinion is this: to the line `int foo = INT_MIN;`, even though it extends to `int foo = -2147483648;`, compiler won't compile the code to `int foo = 2147483648; foo = -foo;`, the code is compiled at once, i.e. compiler parses the AST and directly pass the result to variable. i don't understand why `2147483648` is `long` matters.

Comment: @ouah:`Because 2147483648 is a long value as it does not fit an int` But the number is `-2147483648` and it is part of the range for int.

Comment: @Cratylus `-2147483648` is not an integer constant. `2147483648` is. `-2147483648` is the integer constant `2147483648` with the unary `-` operation.

Comment: i am curious about the practice. could somebody try with compilers and let us know the result of assigning `-2147483648` directly?

Comment: @ouah What about this: http://codepad.org/bnb4UeLS

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr  let's take a system where `2147483648` is of type `long`. Then `int foo = -2147483648;` is the same as `int foo = (long) -2147483648;` which is the same actually as `int foo = INT_MIN;` as `-2147483648` is representable in a 32-bit  `int`.

Comment: @ouah updated with a type-exposing sample (I know, its a C question, but that language doesn't have such a nicety as to expose type info in such a clean manner, and they both share similar `INT_MIN` logic). Hope that's ok.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry I added my own example as yours is C++ but the question is tagged C, feel free to add another answer with your example.

Comment: @ouah no no, yours drives it home nicely. Didn't think of utilizing sizeof. was more interested in exposing the actual *type*, and C++ deduction in concert with gcc's `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` was a handy way to do it. This works. No need for a different answer (and it would be redundant if I did, as yours is clearly the right answer; +1 in case it wasn't blatantly apparent).

Comment: @WhozCraig well I put it back as a second edit :)

Comment: @ouah i don't think compiler will do everything you said separately.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr it certainly won't, it was an example.

Comment: @ouah "You will most likely end up with: 4 8" - http://codepad.org/9TVJMzIu

Comment: @kotlomoy compile it in c99 or c11 mode, by default with  `gcc` you have c89 with extensions and the rules for integer constants are different in c89.

Comment: @ouah OK, your example works in C99: http://ideone.com/wpzCPC. What about adding information about difference between C89 and С99 to your answer?

Comment: Actually, the data type of the integer literal `2147483648`, and by extension `-2147483648`, is `unsigned int` in ISO C90! This is the same as C89.