# How to define a negative number in C

Tags: c

I'm currently working on a project in C and I have an issue with my #defines.
When I'm defining a negative number (for example, #define MIN_W_RANGE -2147483648) the compiler doesn't recognise the minus sign.
I've attached a screenshot of the debug that shows my defines and the values that the compiler recognises.

I have also tried to put the number in brackets, but that also hasn't worked.

What am I doing wrong???

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Have you tried printing it our instead of looking it under the debugger?

Comment: The typical definition is `(-2147483647 - 1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we define INT\_MIN as -INT\_MAX - 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003893/why-do-we-define-int-min-as-int-max-1)

Comment: duplicates: [Why we write TMin32 as -2147483647-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30194153/995714), [How do I define a constant equal to -2147483648?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27612996/995714). See also [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: So what does `printf("%d\n", (int)MIN_W_RANGE);` output? It should print `-2147483648` if `int` is 32-bit 2's complement. (The cast to `(int)` is needed because the type of `MIN_W_RANGE` as defined is likely to be `long` or `long long` depending on the system (which is why `INT_MIN` is typically defined as `(-INT_MAX - 1)` to keep its type as `int`).)

Comment: The screenshot seems to show the **debugger** thinks `MIN_W_RANGE` is a `long long` with value 217483648, but we cannot tell what the **compiler** thinks it is, so we cannot tell whether there is a bug in the compiler, a bug in the debugger, both of those, or something else in the source code you are not showing us. Edit the question to provide a [mre] in text form.

Comment: Show the output of `printf("%s\n", _Generic((MIN_W_RANGE), int: "int", unsigned int: "unsigned int", long: "long", unsigned long: "unsigned long", long long: "long long", unsigned long long: "unsigned long long", default: "unknown")); printf("%lld\n", (long long) (MIN_W_RANGE));` when inserted as the first statements in `main`.

Comment: By the way, we call `(` and `)` parentheses, not brackets. Apologies if folks elsewhere use the words differently, but generally `[` and `]` are brackets and `{` and `}` are braces. The terms do get muddled when mathematicians use them all as multiple levels of parentheses in complicated expressions, but when referring to specific instances, “parentheses” is preferred for `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean with "the compiler doesn't recognise the minus sign".

Each integer constant in your code has a type just like declared variables. Also, C does not have "minus signs" as part of the integer constant, the `-` is the unary minus operator applied *after* the integer constant has been given a type.

`2147483648` is too large to get the type `int` so the compiler will make it `long` or `long long` depending on system. Then it will apply unary `-` and you get `-2147483648` of type `long` or `long long`. (Judging by your debugger output, it seems to be `long long`.)

If you need it to have type `int` then as someone mentioned `(-2147483647 - 1)` is a commonly used trick.

Comment: This tells us why `-2147483648` would produce the value of −2147483648 as a `long` or `long long`. What does that have to do with the debugger saying it has a value of 2147483648?

Answer (score 0):

Debugger reporting `MIN_W_RANGE = (long long) 2147483648` implies debugger has a bug.  The `long long` part is OK, the value is not.   `MIN_W_RANGE = (long long) -2147483648` is expected.

OP reports: "the compiler doesn't recognise the minus sign." is not well supported.  We are seeing the result of the debugger, not directly the compiler.  It *could* be the compiler, I just find debuggers more buggy than compilers.

Seeing more of the code, as *text*, would help.

---

`-2147483648` is a two step: negation of the constant `2147483648`.  `2147483648` is outside the `int` and `long` range here, so is type `long long`.

To form the `int` value of -2147483648, avoid constants outside the `int` range.
Use `(-2147483647 - 1)`

---

> What am I doing wrong???

Using a broken debugger is my first suspect.