# Why can't I use -2147483648 in an expression of `set /A` directly?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

As you might have noticed, -2147483648 = -2<sup>31</sup> is the negative limit of the signed 32-bit integer range.

When I try to use this value literally...:

```
set /A -2147483648
```

..., the following error occurs:

> ```
> Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.
> ```

However, I can state the positive limit 2147483647 = 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 without any trouble:

```
set /A 2147483647
```

So why does `set /A` behave like that, although the number is perfectly within the applicable range for signed two's complement 32-bit integers?

And is there a way to state the constant -2147483648 directly in a `set /A` expression?

I know, I could use a variable that is preset to the value, like `set NEGLIM=-2147483648`, and then use it in an unexpanded way, like `set /A NEGLIM`, but is there not an immediate way of providing that value?

Comment: Because the program treats the number as a positive 32-bit number and then negates it? Just a guess.

Comment: I have investigated this issue, as well as many other issues related to number parsing within CMD.EXE. I published my results at DosTips at [Rules for how CMD.EXE parses numbers](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3758). I think you will find it interesting.

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed, nice work! Thanks a lot for the link! I'm really shocked about the difference in behaviour of `set /A` on Windows XP and later versions... :-O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose the following workaround:

```
set /A -2147483647-1
```

result:

```
-2147483648
```

funny note: `set /A -2147483647-2` yields `2147483647` so toying with the limit is dangerous :)

Comment: If you look at the binary two's complement representation, the result of `set /A -2147483647-2` becomes obvious... ;-)

Comment: the same thing has to be used in C: [Why do we define INT_MIN as -INT_MAX - 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26003893/995714)

Answer (score 2):

I just found an interesting fact: when using hexadecimal representation, the negative limit can be given:

```
set /A -0x80000000
```

Or (also resulting in -2147483648 due to the two's complement representation):

```
set /A +0x80000000
```

However, octal notation fails just like the decimal one:

```
rem These fail:
set /A -020000000000
set /A +020000000000
```