# Why am I able to use INT_MIN without including <climits> header?

Tags: c++

I wrote a program that utilises `INT_MIN`. However, I did not include `<climits>` header file using the `include` directive. But my program still compiled without any errors or warnings. How? Did the compiler automatically include this header file?

Compiled the program using `g++`.

Edit: I only included the `iostream` library.

Comment: did you include other headers?

Comment: `iostream` will include other headers that will include other headers etc.

Comment: Any standard library is allowed to include any other standard library. But don't rely on that, always include what you use.

Comment: It can be included in the precompiled header

Comment: Offtopic: But don't use INT_MIN in C++, use  [std::numeric_limits<int>::min()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). INT_MIN is a macro and has  no type.

Comment: @PepijnKramer actually [`INT_MIN` is typed](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#5.2.4.2.1). That's why [`INT_MIN` must be defined as `-INT_MAX - 1` instead of `-SOMETHING`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26003893/995714). But yes you should prefer `std::numeric_limits` in C++

Comment: @Pepijn Krame in theory - yes bad idea, In practice - numeric limits may not work as you expect with different compilers, or even same compiler but deferent operating systestems. INT_MIN - will work everywhere, and exactly as expected.

Comment: @VictorGubin sounds like FUD, what actual C++ compiler in practice you mean? The std::numeric_limits<int> is there since C++98.

Comment: @phuvlc no there is not type, `#define INT_MAX       2147483647, #define INT_MIN     (-2147483647 - 1)` it is a macro, a typeless number that the preprocessor will just replace.

Comment: @VictorGubin I would be interested in an example. The thing with std::limits is that they play nice with class templates and the macros will not. And these things matter in libraries.

Comment: @PepijnKramer A numeric literal always has a type. You can do `decltype(INT_MAX)` and get `int`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Now you mention it, _I8_MAX       127i8 indeed has the type i8... totally missed that all this time.

Comment: One of my hobby projects was what I called **deader files**.  The deader files were header files that would compile, but not link.  They only provided symbols required, and no more.  They did not include any other header file (unless required by the standard).  They did not pollute the global namespace.  If you missed a standard header file, the code would not compile, because the deader files did not provide implicit dependencies to other standard header (deader) files.

Comment: @Öö Tiib Try contexpr and you'll know, especially with some MS VC++ older version (BTW new version of VC++ is the only compiler fully support STD 2017). Off cause min/max/digit10 etc works for run-time only code with exactly same way as macros.

Comment: @PepijnKramer no [`2147483647` is an `int` literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8108715/995714). In C++ it's even easier to check, just print `typeid(t).name()`

Comment: @VictorGubin Please be precise what version of VS does not support std::numeric_limits? Those that compiled for 16 bit subsystem 30 years ago? But Windows does not have that subsystem anymore. Why to use such compilers?

Comment: @phuclv Yes I learned something today. It can be checked at compile time too : `static_assert(std::is_same_v<int,MAX_INT>);`. As said just stupid I missed this all those years.

Answer (score 0):

To have a less controversial example, consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
    
int main() {
    std::string s{"asd"};
    std::cout << s;
}
```

It compiles without error here https://godbolt.org/z/fWbK4Yc5z.

If you use `std::string` you should include `string`. That does not imply that you can rely on an error when the include is missing. Standard library headers can include other headers. Here it happens that `iostream` apparently includes `string`. This is nothing to rely on. It may change with the next version of the compiler (I used gcc), and it can break on a different compiler.

The (inofficial) rule is: Include what you use. If you use `std::string` you should include `string`. If you use `INT_MIN` you should include `climits`.