# Are intmax_t max and min values unique?

Tags: c

For most integer types, the minimum will be 1 "larger" than the max, right?

Like the range for long long is -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807. When I'm running my program, why is it that both -9223372036854775808 and 9223372036854775808 give me a compiler warning and cause errors, as opposed to only the intmax_t max?

Because the intmax_t min should be valid at -9223372036854775808, no?

Edit: I also tried 9223372036854775807 and -9223372036854775807, they both work fine.

Comment: Can you show us some code that causes these warnings?

Comment: `intmax_t min = -9223372036854775808;` is not valid as `9223372036854775808` is outside the `intmax_t` range.  `intmax_t min = -9223372036854775807 - 1;` is valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(allow me to use 16-bit values for shorter numbers)*

Technically, when you write `-32768` in C, you have written:
*"Negative of the value 32768"*

And 32,768 is too big for a positive 16-bit value, even though -32,768 is valid.

This is why you'll often see in header files like `limits.h`:

```
#define MAX_INT 32767
#define MIN_INT (-MAX_INT - 1)
/* Translates to -32767 - 1 ==> -32768 */
```

---

This question covers essentially the same information:

[Why are there differing definitions of INT64_MIN? And why do they behave differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270084/why-are-there-differing-definitions-of-int64-min-and-why-do-they-behave-differe)

Comment: I'm not sure if this warrants an extra thread, but how would I change the MAX_INT or MIN_INT of an external header file? Is there any way I can make the min value valid for <stdint.h>? Well, I guess it's just giving me extra work since I'll have to deal with the minimum once I apply that, but I think it'll be useful to know.

Comment: The short answer is you cannot increase `INT_MAX` (or decrease `INT_MIN`) from values other than those specified in `limits.h`. Why? Because they are already set to the max/min that is possible for the number of bits per type. Anything larger than `INT_MAX` would require 33-bits instead of 32-bits.